# On running xdg-settings get default-we-browser, I get the following message "unknown desktop environment"

Tags: linux, rhel, r, xdg, xdg-open

I am running an R script that tries to open a link on the linux server.
But on running the script, I get the following error
**xdg-open: no method available for opening 'https://unix.stackexchange.com/'**
So I ran `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` which throws the error message:
**xdg-settings:  "unknown desktop environment"**

I have tried to set the parameter $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP in the .bashrc profile in $HOME/.bashrc
by adding the line `export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE`
But this didn't resolve the issue.

**How can I resolve the issue with xdg-open.**

Help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: OS release details: NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server" VERSION="7.5 (Maipo)"